# accidentally added file but added git ignore later

Tags: linux, git, github

in my local I pushed a version to my server, says `abc.env`. Then I fix it in my local by adding `abc.env` to `.gitignore`, did `git commit` and `push`. Then I ssh into my server, do `git pull`, found that `abc.env` is still there? How do I fix it?

Comment: adding to .gitignore does nothing if the file is already tracked by git (it's part of the project history, say). You could then do `git rm --cached thefile` and commit so that then it's gone from branch history moving forward..... but you might also consider removing it from the history altogether so that it's gone from branch history as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete abc.env from the github repo.
Please use the following steps
1. remove abc.env from .gitignore file
2. delete abc.env and push the changes
3. add abc.env back to .gitignore file.

if you are using any git clients like gitDesktop or Source tree, it will be easy to follow these steps

Comment: I need the .env in my development, why delete it in local?

Comment: I suggest you take a backup of abc.env from a local folder. Delete and push the changes to git repo. and add it back to gitignore file. Then copy the file from backup folder to your local work space folder

Comment: No need to delete the file, do `git rm --cached <file>`